# Grant All Syntax

Tags: mysql

This isn't working:

```
use mysql

GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'192.168.1.2'
```

Nor is

```
use mysql

GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'192.168.1.2' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'192.168.1.2'' at line 3
```

I'm on server version 5.5.8. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
use mysql

GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root@192.168.1.2' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'
```